# Macbook Pro can't connect to internal hard drive even after changing the cable to the main circuit board

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, hardware, motherboard

So I thought my macbook's hard drive crashed last month when a folder with a question mark didn't allow me to use it. I got it replaced, but shortly after, the problem persisted. I thought it would be the connection between the hard drive and the main circuits, so i changed that wire. It worked again for a couple of hours, but then my computer froze and the question mark popped up again. I bought an enclosure and am now using it with my original hard drive that i thought crashed.  I have no idea what to do with my life right now. Classes just started and I need this piece of technology. Someone help me.

Answer (score 1):

First step would be try the [Apple Hardware Test](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1509) or [Apple Diagnostics](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5781), depending on whether your machine is pre or post 2013

Plug the machine into the mains power, boot then hold the  <kbd>D</kbd>  key until the test screen appears.